# Facebook PHP SDK retrieve current location of user

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

So far I have tried:

```
$facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"location"));
```

Which returns:

```
Array ( [location] => Array ( [id] => 107847249250173 [name] => Cambridge, Cambridgeshire ) [id] => 1234567890 )
```

If I have the necessary permissions, how could I echo just the `[name]` bit (so the output is "Cambridge, Cambridgeshire") in a format that could be inserted into a database?

Comment: Why can't you just access that key in the array? `$loc_name = $output['location']['name'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = $facebook->api('/me', 'get', array("fields"=>"location"));
echo $data['location']['name'];
```

Comment: While the question does ask how to echo the location name, it says that the goal is to acquire the name in order to insert it into a database, so actually using `echo` here isn't entirely correct. Regardless, +1.

Comment: @Vulcan yes agreed with you.